# Probability distribution of speed at a given time vs probability distribution of speed at a given position

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, change-of-variable

Here is a cute problem; I am looking for a **straightforward proof**.

Consider you are in a car that drives on a one-way street, and its speed is a random function of time. You are given a probability distribution for the speed of the car at any given **time**. This distribution is stationary in time and independent of the position.

Now consider an observer sitting at a fixed **position** on the road measuring the speed at which you cross the position. What is the probability distribution of your speed as measured by this observer?

If the probability density function of the speed at a given time is given by $f(v)$ with some average value $\bar v\equiv \int_0^\infty v f(v)\, dv$, the answer (the probability density function $g(v)$ of speed as measured by the observer at a fixed position) is given by
$$
g(v) = \frac{v}{\bar v} f(v). 
$$
This says that the probability of observing a particular speed $v$ at a given position is skewed toward faster speeds.

Since the solution looks simple and general, I think there should be a straightforward derivation for this. I am looking for a derivation that is clear but simple (for someone who understands probability but has not taken a formal measure-theoretic course on probability, think of scientists and engineers).

**Edit**: Let me clarify some things that showed up in the comments. For the application I have in mind, the car speed is a continuous-time stationary stochastic process (I'm hoping this detail isn't needed for the proof, but just in case). The speed can be a continuous or discontinuous function of time. The position is not random. The statement of the problem holds for any fixed position. Since as Henry mentioned in the comments, this really looks like it should be a simple change of variable, I am looking for a straightforward derivation that is also general.

Comment: This is essentially a [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)

Comment: @Henry But is it, really? Can you write a clear derivation?

Comment: If you want an explanation that is clear, you would do better to illustrate with an example where the distribution was limited to a finite (or countable) number of speeds.  For example suppose that you had a probability $p$ at any time of travelling at $a$ metres/second and $q=1-p$ of travelling at $b$ m/s.  Then in $t$ seconds you would expect to travel $apt$ metres at speed $a$ and $bqt$ at speed $b$, so the proportion of distance travelled at $a$ (i.e. the probability of being measured at that speed at a point in the road) would be $\frac{ap}{ap+bq}$. Extend to more speeds and the limit

Comment: It's confusing to say the car's speed is a random function of time. Does the car sample a random speed from the given distribution at every instant and undergo infinite acceleration in order to reach it? A highly discontinuous velocity function is likely not the derivative of any position function.

Comment: To fix this, you could consider the car's trajectory to be fixed and consider the observed speed when choosing a point in time uniformly at random vs. when choosing a position uniformly at random.

Comment: @Karl for the application I have in mind, the car speed is a continuous-time stationary stochastic process. The speed can be a continuous or discontinuous function of time. The position is not random. The statement of the problem holds for any fixed position.

Comment: @Henry yes, this is a good way to understand the answer, and this is how I came up with the solution. But as you mentioned, it looks like it should be a simple change of variable, so I am looking for a straightforward derivation that is general

Comment: @Karl This is a one-way street so presumably the velocity is bounded between $0$ and the speed of light.  I would presume that makes it integrable to give distance and the derivative of distance is then differentiable to give velocity (the original velocity apart perhaps from a set of measure $0$)

Answer (score 0):

You are more likely to be at a spot where the car is faster since the car covers longer intervals when it is faster--assuming your location is uniformly chosen along the way.

Comment: This is a good explanation for the skew toward faster speed. But I want a clear derivation for the relationship between $g$ and $f$?  Also, the relationship should hold for any fixed position, not averaged over uniformly chosen positions along the way.